# How can i place two buttons side by side with an image at the bottom of the button?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-button

How can i place two buttons side by side with an image at the bottom of the button?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/a_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:text="Button-a" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:text="Button-b" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Wrap above layout in another vertically oriented `LinearLayout`, or use another `ViewGroup` more suitable for the job, e.g. a `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Do you want an image for both the buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using button u can use linear-layout(Clickable) and use its id instead of Button id.something like this...... Using this you can customize your Button as per your requirements.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

//Button-A

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/a_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:clickable="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="Text-A"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
             />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/image_A"
            android:paddingTop="13dip"  />

    </LinearLayout>
```

//For Horizontal partition line

```
     <TextView
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#303030"
        android:paddingTop="20dip" />
```

//Button-B

```
     <LinearLayout

         android:id="@+id/b_button"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_weight="0.50"
         android:orientation="vertical" 
     android:clickable="true">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text-B"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:paddingTop="10dip" />

        <ImageView
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:scaleType="fitXY"
             android:src="@drawable/image_B"
             android:paddingTop="13dip"
              />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add below line to both your buttons and specify the drawable you want to use.

```
android:drawableBottom="@drawable/image"
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**
Above method works if you want to use your drawables as it is i.e. without modifying its dimensions. If you wish you modify you drawable dimentions as well then you can do that through simple Java code written below:

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.button)).setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.image, 25));
```

.....
.....

```
Drawable getDrawable(Context context, int drawable, float form_factor) {
    Drawable imgDrawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(drawable);
    imgDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int)form_factor, (int)form_factor);
    return imgDrawable;
}
```

Comment: I have updated my solution if you wish to alter dimentions of the drawable you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can place images at the bottom of buttons with the Drawable_Bottom property.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
style="@android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/a_button"
    style="@android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableBottom="@android:drawable/btn_star"
    android:text="Button-a" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_button"
    style="@android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableBottom="@android:drawable/btn_star"
    android:text="Button-b" />

</LinearLayout>
```